# Ionic CORS issue on iOS device, while correct headers are set

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, cors

I have some issue with ionic CORS on an iOS device. Now, I know that CORS issue should be solved mainly from the server. As I have fool control over the backend I set the following headers on the Apache Vhosts file.

```
   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
   Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
   Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
```

And it works, I have inspected headers and see that they are set. Android app works without any issue both in simulators and live devices. iOS app also works without any issue in any simulator I try. So it seems that the only issue I have is on a real iPhone that doesn't run app and shows CORS error.
As can be seen from the headers I have allowed anything that was possible to allow and don't get why the webview throws the error on an iOS device while all the headers are set correctly.

Here is some more info about my ionic setup

```
   Ionic CLI          : 6.10.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0, ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 18 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : 1.0.0

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/someuser/Library/Android/sdk)
   NodeJS            : v12.18.2 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.14.5
   OS                : macOS Catalina
   Xcode             : Xcode 11.6 Build version 11E708
```

Here is the error I get

```
 [Error] Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://app.example.com/oauth/token due to access control checks.
[Error] Backend returned code 0, body was: {"isTrusted":true}
    (anonymous function) (cordova.js:1732)
    handleErrors (main.js:2334)
    error (vendor.js:68778)
    _error (vendor.js:98287)
    error (vendor.js:20453)
    _error (vendor.js:20479)
    error (vendor.js:20453)
    _error (vendor.js:20479)
    error (vendor.js:20453)
    notifyError (vendor.js:22047)
    _error (vendor.js:140032)
    error (vendor.js:20453)
    _error (vendor.js:20479)
    error (vendor.js:20453)
    onError (vendor.js:62444)
    onInvokeTask (vendor.js:5126)
    runTask (polyfills.js:3:10845)
    invokeTask (polyfills.js:3:16802)
    p (polyfills.js:2:27655)
    v (polyfills.js:2:27895)
[Error] Failed to load resource: Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers. (token, line 0)
```

Here are plugins installed

```
> cordova plugin ls
com-badrit-base64 0.2.0 "Base64"
cordova-plugin-advanced-http 1.11.1 "Advanced HTTP plugin"
cordova-plugin-app-version 0.1.9 "AppVersion"
cordova-plugin-badge 0.8.8 "Badge"
cordova-plugin-camera 4.1.0 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.3 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.2 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.2 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.7.1 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.2 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 3.2.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-local-notification 0.9.0-beta.3 "LocalNotification"
cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.2 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy 2.3.0 "Request Location Accuracy"
cordova-plugin-screen-orientation 3.0.2 "Screen Orientation"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.4 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-uniquedeviceid 1.3.2 "UniqueDeviceID"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.4 "Whitelist"
cordova-sqlite-storage 2.6.0 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin"
cordova.plugins.diagnostic 4.0.12 "Diagnostic"
es6-promise-plugin 4.2.2 "Promise"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending several hours on debugging, I found out that the issue was that it doesn't accept wildcard for Access-Control-Allow-Methods and Access-Control-Allow-Headers
So the server headers look like this now.

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Content-Type, Authorization, Accept, timeout"
```

The one drawback of this that I had to inspect all the code and include all the HTTP methods and headers that are in use throughout the app.
My understanding is that the issue was because of the Authorization header which cannot be wildcarded. And because it contains credentials, methods should be stated explicitly as well.

Now it works in all devices and simulators.